# How to retain scroll position in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I'm working with a UWP application that uses a DataGrid. From time to time I need to reload the data in the DataGrid from a database. When I do this, the DataGrid's scroll position resets to the top. I'd like it to either stay where it is, or at least, I'd like to be able to determine the current scroll position or the current visible rows and scroll back there myself.

The only function I can find in DataGrid related to scrolling is "ScrollIntoView", but it requires that I know the item I want to scroll to. I don't see a way to determine what that item is.

Thanks.

Comment: No experience here, but: before you reload your data, find the item in the middle of your current view. Then do the reload. Finally, scan through the reloaded data, finding that previous item somehow. Then call `ScrollIntoView`. You may need to play around a bit to get this to work, but I've done it in other scrollable views in other frameworks. Another alternative is to do it via "percent through the list". Count the items displayed, get the index of one of the displayed items, calculate percentage. Then after the reload, do it in reverse to figure out which item to _scroll into view_

Comment: I don't know how to find the item in the middle of the view, or count the items displayed. Can you explain?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Never used UWP. It appears that the UWP docs could be better. I'm pretty sure that somewhere (either on the grid object or some helper object) there's a property that tells you what it is displaying. You may have to look at the collection of row-ish things that are bound to the grid

Comment: My research seems to indicate that there is not in fact any way to do this, which is surprising. One would think that this is a common operation people need. I'm now going to have to tell my customer it's impossible to do what he wants, which is going to be hard for him to understand.

Comment: Suggestion: create a very simple UWP app with a data grid. Bind it to a list with more items than can fit. Put a single button on the form that "refreshes" grid. Now create a [mre] with a very directed question: "How can I refresh this while keeping the current item displayed?" Show as much code as makes sense. You may want to add a `xaml` tag; I somehow expect that WPF and MAUI have similar issues. I only have minor XAML experience  (and only with WPF), but what I remember was there was always a way to do what I wanted, but it wasn't always clear how to get to the solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API to get the position of the current table in `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGird`. You need to get the `ScrollBar` of `DataGird` through [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621), and then calculate the current index of rows based on the default height of DataGird's row 32. Finally, use ScrollIntoView  to reach to the correct position.

You can refer to the following code, I cleared the collection and re-added the elements to mimic your database update.

```
<Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" 
        Height="600" Margin="12"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Loaded="MyDataGrid_Loaded"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customers}" />
        
        <Button Content="Add data" Margin="211,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
   
</Grid>
```

---

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Customers.Add(new Customer("1.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("2.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("3.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("4.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("5.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("6.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("7.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("8.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("9.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("10.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("11.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("12.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("13.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("14.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("15.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("16.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",

                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("17.", "Zero",
               "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
               false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("18.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("19.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("20.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("21.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("22.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("23.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("24.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("25.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("26.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",

                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("27.", "Zero",
               "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
               false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("28.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("29.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("30.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("31.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("32.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("33.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("34.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("35.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));

        }

      
        private void MyDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollbar = MyFindDataGridChildOfType<ScrollBar>(MyDataGrid);
            scrollbar.ValueChanged += Scroll_ValueChanged;
        }

        public static T MyFindDataGridChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
        {
            var MyQueue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
            MyQueue.Enqueue(root);
            while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                DependencyObject current = MyQueue.Dequeue();
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                    var typedChild = child as T;
                    if (typedChild != null)
                    {
                        return typedChild;
                    }
                    MyQueue.Enqueue(child);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        int index=0;
        private void Scroll_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             index = (int)(e.NewValue) / 32 + ((int)MyDataGrid.Height / 32);
        }


        private  void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollbar = MyFindDataGridChildOfType<ScrollBar>(MyDataGrid);
            scrollbar.ValueChanged -= Scroll_ValueChanged;

            Customers.Clear();
            Customers.Add(new Customer("1.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("2.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("3.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("4.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("5.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("6.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("7.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("8.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("9.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("10.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("11.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("12.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("13.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("14.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("15.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("16.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",

                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("17.", "Zero",
               "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
               false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("18.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("19.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("20.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("21.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("22.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("23.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("24.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("25.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("26.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",

                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("27.", "Zero",
               "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
               false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("28.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("29.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("30.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("31.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("32.", "Two",
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("33.", "Three",
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10",
                true));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("34.", "Zero",
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45",
                false));
            Customers.Add(new Customer("35.", "One",
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67",
                false));

            MyDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(Customers[index], null);
            scrollbar.ValueChanged += Scroll_ValueChanged;
        }

    }
}
    
public class Customer
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsNew { get; set; }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName,
        String address, Boolean isNew)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Address = address;
        this.IsNew = isNew;
    }

      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a rather complicated solution. Instead of just replacing the old data with the new data, I had to carefully merge the new data into the old data. That means for every item that is different, I had to update all of the fields of the existing item while retaining the original object. Any new items are inserted into the array at the proper location, and finally any items that might have been deleted need to be removed.

It's a lot of work for such a simple task, and it's much slower than just replacing the list, but it's good enough.

Comment: Have you considered my solution? Calculate the position of the ScrollBar to get the current row of datagrid.